# How do I save relational data from the client to Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

In my Xamarin.Forms project there is a `Category` model which contains a list of `Grades`. The user must be able to select a `Category` and add a new `Grade` to it. However, I'm having trouble saving the `Grade` with a relationship to a parent `Category`.

**Question:** How do I add the `Grade` with reference to an existing parent `Category`?
My code is essentially doing the following to add a new `Grade`.

```
Category category = await cloudService.GetDefaultCategory();
Grade grade = new Grade() { Title = "Grade 1", Category = category };
await gradeTable.CreateItemAsync(Grade); // this is an IMobileServiceTable
```

When I attempt this, I get the following error.

> The operation failed due to a conflict: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Categories'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Categories'. The duplicate key value is (DA289023-09DC-45B8-B277-C3546E99F2DA).

#### Client models

```
public class Category : TableData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
}
public class Grade : TableData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
public abstract class TableData
{        
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

#### Server models

```
public class Category : EntityData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
}
public class Grade : EntityData
{        
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You could try to add different partition key Id to distinguish `Category` and `Grade` model.

Comment: @JoeyCai, could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: The Azure SDK won't manage the relationship for you. Add a CategoryId property to the Grade class, and set it before sending the Grade record to your server. See also Adrian Hall's chapter on Relationships: https://adrianhall.gitlab.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eric said, you need to add a `CategoryId` property to the Grade class. The `Id` in `TableData` is primary key in remote store but it could not manage the relationship for you.

```
public class Grade : TableData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category : TableData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/05/27/retrieving-data-from-1n-relationship-using-net-backend-azure-mobile-services/) and this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/06/18/insertupdate-data-with-1n-relationship-using-net-backend-azure-mobile-services/) about 1:n relationship with mobile service.